# Active Directory management tools for medium sized forest (less than 1000 users)

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

What are good AD management tools for AD forests with less than 1000 users and 3 domains across three locations?

Specifically looking for:
-Bulk users creation
-Security groups management
-Performance monitoring

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that size, how about just built-in and other free Microsoft tools? Like add users with dsadd, security groups with ADUC, and perfmon? Plus some good ol' scripting?

Answer (score 0):

[ADManager Plus](https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/) from [MangeEngine](https://www.manageengine.com/) is a very useful and richly featured application that is accessed via a web browser.  We're using it in our organisation (15k+ users accounts, 4 domains, worldwide locations) and it has helped to reduce manual overhead, managed rights delegation, and much more.

It's also multi-domain aware, and the dashboard (with all the AD statistics and charts) is really handy too.  Also, it offers a user Self Service portal to allow users to update their own details (all controlled by you) in case their contact details change etc.

They offer a 30-day trial, and even a [usable online demo](https://demo.admanagerplus.com/) (click on Administrator Demo, Help Desk Users demo, or Self Service Portal demo)

[image: Bulk User Workflow]
<sub>(source: [manageengine.com](http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/images/bulk_user_management_proces.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Adaxes Active Directory management solution](http://adaxes.com) from Softerra.

It completely fulfills your requirements and has more useful features. Detailed information on the product you can find on their site, there are demo videos and screen shots on how to use the tool and its specific features.

The tool is accessed via a web browser. They offer a reliable support and educational/government/non-profits discounts. You can download Adaxes and use it 30 days for free.

Answer (score 0):

> Bulk users creation

dsadd from a script, or ldifde, csvde

> Security groups management

What do you need to "manage" that the built-in or RK tools (ADUC, dsadd, dsmod, etc) don't provide?

> Performance monitoring

You don't really monitor performance of AD. You can monitor the health of AD with tools like nltest, dcdiag, Ntdsutil, replmon, as well as reviewing your system and application logs from time to time. A central logging server is a good idea to aid with this. You can monitor the performance of your DCs (or any of your servers) with built-in tools like perfmon, or add-ons ranging from SCOM to HPOV, or vendor-specific tools like IBM Directory, HP SIM, or a generic free tool like MRTG using SNMP.